# Powershell cmdlet removing whitespace

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I've created a small cmdlet in for Powershell to be able to send an e-mail using exchange services.  When I pass the body of the message in Powershell seems to be stripping all whitespace out of the string.

Here is the cmdlet code:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Send, "ExchangeEmail")]
public class SendExchageEmailCommand : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public string ServerUri { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [ValidatePattern("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&amp;])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$")]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [ValidatePattern("^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[-._+&amp;])*[0-9a-zA-Z]+@([-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$")]
    [Parameter]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1) {Url = new Uri(ServerUri)};

        var mail = new EmailMessage(service) {Subject = Subject};

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(From))
        {
            mail.From = From;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Body))
        {
            mail.Body = Body;
        }

        mail.ToRecipients.Add(To);

        mail.Send();
    }
}
```

And the PowerShell code looks like:

```
$subject = "Testing Reports"

$body = ""
$files = Get-ChildItem $ReportsFolder
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $body += "`r`n"
    $body += $file.FullName
}

Send-ExchangeEmail -ServerUri $SMTPServerURI -Subject $subject -To $MessageTo -Body $body
```

Is there any way to ensure that whitespace is passed into a cmdlet (and am I even right that it is PS stripping the whitespace?)

Comment: I don't think that PowerShell is removing whitespace. I find it more likely that you're sending the e-mail body as if it was HTML, not plain text. I don't know what class EmailMessage is (since I don't know the namespace or anything), but in the MailMessage class there is a flag for IsBodyHtml, which you can set. On the other hand, depending on which version of PowerShell you have, there might already be a Send-MailMessage cmdlet built-in.

Comment: What is the advantage of this method over using `send-mailmessage` with your Exchange server as the SMTP host? On the surface, it looks like you've reinvented that cmdlet with no additional functionality.

Comment: @robert: if you promote your comment to answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @alroc: my client won't give me access to an SMTP endpoint.  The Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices library works directly with Exchange which is my only choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that PowerShell is removing whitespace. I find it more likely that you're sending the e-mail body as if it was HTML, not plain text. I don't know what class EmailMessage is (since I don't know the namespace or anything), but in the MailMessage class there is a flag for IsBodyHtml, which you can set.